# text-overflow: ellipsis doesn't appear to be working

Tags: css

I have a nav menu in an unordered list:

```
<ul>        
    <li class="current">
        <a href="./">Home</a>
    </li>           
    <li class="">
        <a href="./location/">Location</a>
    </li>           
    <li class="">
        <a href="./rooms-and-rates/">Rooms &amp; Rates </a>
    </li>           
    <li class="">
        <a href="./facilities/">Facilities</a>
    </li>           
    <li class="">
        <a href="./things-to-do/">Things to do</a>
    </li>           
    <li class="">
        <a href="./eating-and-drinking/">Eating and Drinking</a>
    </li>           
</ul>
```

When the menu title is too long, I need to use text-overflow: ellipsis so I am styling my menu links like so in my CSS:

```
    header nav ul li a { text-decoration: none; 
       text-overflow: ellipsis; 
       display: block; 
       overflow: hidden; 
       width: 150px; 
       height: 32px;
}
```

However, the desired effect is not happening. It is just cutting off the whole last word (and wrapping it where it is not visible). Is there anything wrong with my code or is there some caveat that I'm unaware of with text-overflow: ellipsis?

Comment: Just from a design point of view, I wouldn't cut off link names...You want the user to know exactly where their going, not half of where their going.

Comment: Are you sure your browser is compatible and supports `text-overflow`? See http://www.quirksmode.org/css/textoverflow.html

Comment: You might want to see [why text overflow ellipsis doesn't work](https://semicolon.dev/tutorial/css/text-overflow-ellipsis-doesnt-work) tutorial, which lists  what's required for ellipsis to properly show up at the minimum.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You need to add `white-space: nowrap;` for `text-overflow: ellipsis;` to work.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/Dc7UA/

#### Output:

[image]

#### CSS:

```css
a { 
    text-decoration: none; 
    text-overflow: ellipsis; 
    display: block; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 80px; 
    height: 32px;
}
```

Comment: For me `overflow:hidden;` is sufficient, no need for `white-space`

Comment: @Zaffy it actually doesn't work without `overflow: hidden;`.

Comment: for me ellipsis didnt work with `display: flex`

Comment: @godblessstrawberry because by design flex doesn't overflow. You need to wrap it in a span and set [text overflow](https://semicolon.dev/tutorial/css/text-overflow-ellipsis-doesnt-work) properties to the span instead.

Answer (score 13):

Actually *overflow:hidden;* is required, so you'll probably need those three lines:

```
text-overflow: ellipsis; 
display: block; 
overflow: hidden;
```