# <li> text-overflow. Different results in different browsers

Tags: css, cross-browser

I'm having the same issue described here: [text-overflow: ellipsis doesn't appear to be working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387481/text-overflow-ellipsis-doesnt-appear-to-be-working)

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/Dc7UA/

```
ul a { 
    text-decoration: none; 
    text-overflow: ellipsis; 
    display: block; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 80px; 
    height: 32px;
}
```

The problem is, it only works in Firefox. IE will mess with the bullet indicators. Opera it will hide the bullet indicators.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Is there a way to make them work as in Firefox?

relevant code and snippet below

```css
ul a { 
    text-decoration: none; 
    text-overflow: ellipsis; 
    display: block; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 80px; 
    height: 32px;
}
```

```html
<ul>        
    <li class="current">
        <a href="./">Home</a>
    </li>           
    <li class="">
        <a href="./location/">Location</a>
    </li>           
    <li class="">
        <a href="./rooms-and-rates/">Rooms &amp; Rates </a>
    </li>           
    <li class="">
        <a href="./facilities/">Facilities</a>
    </li>           
    <li class="">
        <a href="./things-to-do/">Things to do</a>
    </li>           
    <li class="">
        <a href="./eating-and-drinking/">Eating and Drinking</a>
    </li>           
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The changes I made were to have a set `font-size` & `font-family` just to make sure it was consistent. I then allowed the height to be auto rather than set manually. I updated the display to `inline-block` for a better display and used the list item itself to create spacing.

**CSS:**

```
li {
    margin: 0 0 5px;
}

ul a {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Arial;
    width: 80px;
    height: auto;
}
```

[**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Dc7UA/220/)

Comment: Works. tricky though. `display: inline-block;` and `height: auto;` made the difference

Comment: Hi @Azevedo glad it worked for you :) Which part did you think was tricky just for future reference?