# Text-overflow: ellipsis does not work as intendent. Spilling outside of view

Tags: html, css

I not familiar with css styling but I want to change overflowing type to ellipsis in my text. But instead of shortening text it is making it longer(spilling outside of div).

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
 body {
  width: 100px;
 }
 .displayInline {
  display: inline;
 }
 .infoCellArea {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100px;
  height: 4.0em;
  overflow: hidden;
 }
 .infoArea {
  height: 4.0em;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow: hidden;
 }
 .maxWidth {
  width: 100px;
 }
 .inline {
  display: inline;
 }
 .taskNameStyle {
  font-weight: 500;
  padding-right: 0.1em;
 }
 .dateStyle {
  padding-left: 0.1em;
  padding-right: 0.1em;
 }
 .titleStyle {
  paddingLeft: 0.1em;
 }
 .cellContent {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  font-size: 0.8571em;
  color: #888;
 }
 .noWrap{
  white-space: nowrap;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div tabindex="0" class="infoCellArea displayInline noWrap">
 <div class="infoArea maxWidth">
  <div class="inline taskNameStyle">Test</div> - 
  <div class="inline dateStyle">Wednesday</div> - 
  <div class="inline titleStyle">Done</div> 
  <div class="cellContent">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</div>
 </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I read that I cannot use `%` as width and need overflow set as hidden but it seems I am doing it not good.
I would like to achive something like "Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ips..."
Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [text-overflow: ellipsis doesn't appear to be working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387481/text-overflow-ellipsis-doesnt-appear-to-be-working)

Comment: @DogukanCavus I used noWrap. Read post first.

Comment: Also you should use `display:block`, `white-space:nowrap` and `max-width`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `.maxWidth` from `.infoArea` class and add `.maxWidth` class in `.cellContent`.

```css
body {
  width: 100px;
 }
 .displayInline {
  display: inline;
 }
 .infoCellArea {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100px;
  height: 4.0em;
  overflow: hidden;
 }
 .infoArea {
  height: 4.0em;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow: hidden;
 }
 .maxWidth {
  width: 100px;
 }
 .inline {
  display: inline;
 }
 .taskNameStyle {
  font-weight: 500;
  padding-right: 0.1em;
 }
 .dateStyle {
  padding-left: 0.1em;
  padding-right: 0.1em;
 }
 .titleStyle {
  paddingLeft: 0.1em;
 }
 .cellContent {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  font-size: 0.8571em;
  color: #888;
 }
 .noWrap{
  white-space: nowrap;
 }
```

```html
<div tabindex="0" class="infoCellArea displayInline noWrap">
 <div class="infoArea">
  <div class="inline taskNameStyle">Test</div> - 
  <div class="inline dateStyle">Wednesday</div> - 
  <div class="inline titleStyle">Done</div> 
  <div class="cellContent maxWidth">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</div>
 </div>
</div>
```